# How to pass JSON with newline \n from flask backend to Jinja2 and JQuery frontend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flask, jinja2

I am trying to pass an array of dictionaries contain escape characters from my flask backend to Jinja2 with JS.

```
'[{"id": 3, "tags": "t2", "content": "B"}, {"id": 5, "tags": "t3", "content": "C,\\nD"}]'
```

I create it with

```
    contents = Content.query.all()
    contents_list = [content.to_dict() for content in contents]
    contents_json = json.dumps(contents_list)
```

I then pass contents_json forward.
from a database

[image: Database screenshot]

without the \n it works fine.

```
'[{"id": 3, "tags": "t2", "content": "B"}, {"id": 5, "tags": "t3", "content": "C,D"}]'
```

but with the newline I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string
> literal at line 1 column 81 of the JSON data
>  http://127.0.0.1:5000/:25
> jQuery 13
> e
> t
> setTimeout handler*Deferred/then/l/<
> c
> fireWith
> fire
> c
> fireWith
> ready
> q
> EventListener.handleEvent*
>
>
> 127.0.0.1:5000:25:23

I've tried

```
  var contents = JSON.parse('{{ contents_json |tojson| safe }}');
```

and

```
  var contents = JSON.parse('{{ contents_json | safe }}');
```

I'm looking for a fix that will work with many different special characters because content will have markdown formatting characters.

Comment: Have you tried passing the list to the template without converting it to json and then using the jinja filter `tojson`? `var contents = {{ contents_list | tojson }};`

Comment: The JSON is valid on its own. You should be able to just pass the string.

Comment: What happens when you chain `encode('utf-8')` to `json.dumps()`?

Comment: Please share a runnable [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: @Detlef yes, same error

Answer (score 0):

It works now with

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def home():
    contents = Content.query.all()
    contents_list = []
    for content in contents:
        content_dict = content.to_dict() 
        if 'content' in content_dict:
            content_dict['content'] = content_dict['content'].replace("\n", "\\n")
        contents_list.append(content_dict)

    return render_template("editClick.html", contents_json=contents_list)
```

Then in the Jinja template

```
  var contents = JSON.parse('{{ contents_list| tojson |safe }}');
```

It was Python escaping the \n that was causing the issue.